# Admin account appearing in People Search Results

Tags: user-profile-service, people-search

I have created a Staff Directory by using the "People Search Results" page available in SP 2010. I followed these instructions: http://www.chakkaradeep.com/post/Put-People-First-%E2%80%93-Building-a-Staff-Directory.aspx

The search results and refinements panel are both working fine.

The problem I have is that one of the admin accounts (setupAdmin) is appearing in the search results. I have tried configuring the UPS to exclude this account by editing the connection filters. The setupAdmin account does not have a first or last name in AD so I have set filters up for both givenName and sn:

givename is not present
sn is not present

But after a Full Profile Sync and a Full Search Crawl the setupAdmin account still appears in the search results.

Does anyone have any ideas why and how I can resolve this please?

Nigel

Answer (score 1):

You could add a filter to the UPS connection to remove accounts with the prefix of the SharePoint service accounts. For example, if your accounts are all "svc_SP*" you could have a filter that ignores those in the UPS sync, which would obviously prevent search from indexing the profile.

I tend to use my setup account as a test for MySites and UPS--obviously doing this would prevent that from being a possibility.

*Edit*: if you're going this route, you'd want your rule based off of the userPrincipalName (login).

Comment: How are you suggesting that I create the filter? I have edited the connection filter to exclude where the samaccountname begins with setup and the setupAdmin account still appears in search results. Even after a Full Profile Sync and a Full Search Crawl. Thanks.

Comment: Note that when an account is excluded from the sync, it will typically take three synchronizations of UPS before the profile/MySite is deleted. This prevents accidental removal of profile data in the case of a synchronization glitch. My guess is that your setup account is still in the profile store. From "Manage Profiles" you can remove the user profile for the account manually, then run a new search crawl. That should remove the account. Additionally, if you do that and the account comes back after a UPS sync, then your filter is incorrect.

Comment: Hi, I thought that if I removed the user from the profile store and did a Full Search Crawl that the user would be deleted as well. But this didn't work. I delete the user profile and then check it is not displaying under "Manage User Profiles". I then run a Full Search Crawl and the account still appears in the People Search results. So I went back to the "Manage User Profiles" and it is appearing again. Any other thoughts?

Comment: I've managed to use a workaround to resolve this. I editing the People Search Scope and creating an exclude rule where "username = setupAdmin".